# Ansible playbook - how to add 2 blocks (and not replace one with another)?

Tags: linux, ansible

How to add 2 blocks when running Ansible playbook?

This is a YML file that I have:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    orcl_packages:
      - "gcc"
      - "gcc-c++"
      - "git"
      - "java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64"

  tasks:
    - name: CreateLocalGroup
      group:
        name: users
        state: present

    - name: Append to file
      blockinfile:
        path: /var/tmp/elasticsearch-7.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml
        insertafter: EOF
        block: |

              node.name: mymaster
              cluster.name: mycluster
              cluster.initial_master_nodes: mymaster
              network.host: [_local_, _site_]
              node.master: true
              node.data: false
              xpack.security.enabled: true

    - name: Append to sysctl file
      blockinfile:
        path: /var/tmp/elasticsearch-7.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml
        insertafter: EOF
        block: |

              discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [{{ master_host }}]
      when: (env == 'SLAVE')
```

Right now - it seems like last block is being replaced with empty line.

Comment: Why does one of the tasks need a "become_user" and the other doesn't when they both operate on the same file?

Comment: Adjusted that part.

Comment: And what is it being replaced with?  There seems to be something missing, I'd expect **something** to follow that colon on the last line of your post .... ;)

Comment: Nothing - empty line :)

Comment: "`it seems like last block is being replaced with empty line`". Too many open questions. It seems? What is the last block? What it was before?   I downvoted.

Comment: Yep - it is....

Comment: You can downvote all you want - answer is accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add unique markers to each of the tasks. For example:

```
    - name: Append to file
      blockinfile:
        marker: "# {mark} block 1"
        path: /var/tmp/elasticsearch-7.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml
        insertafter: EOF
        block: |
              node.name: mymaster
              cluster.name: mycluster
              cluster.initial_master_nodes: mymaster
              network.host: [_local_, _site_]
              node.master: true
              node.data: false
              xpack.security.enabled: true

    - name: Append to sysctl file
      blockinfile:
        marker: "# {mark} block 2"
        path: /var/tmp/elasticsearch-7.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml
        insertafter: EOF
        block: |
              discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [{{ master_host }}]
      when: (env == 'SLAVE')
```